# Mi Hook cambia el precio de todas mis tarjetas mapeadas usando el Select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Hice un componente funcional que crea tarjetas segun un arreglo de objetos que tiene 4 productos. Cada tarjeta que se genera tiene una imagen, un titulo, un precio, y una cantidad (todos específicos segun el producto) Quiero que cuando seleccione la cantidad a comprar de cualquier producto se actualice solo el precio mostrado en la tarjeta. Pero al hacerlo, se me cambian los precios de todas las tarjetas. ¿Como puedo hacer para que solo se cambie la de la tarjeta que estoy cambiando mediante el select? Dejo el codigo del componente, y dejo el codigo del arreglo de objetos del producto.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import data from '../data';


export const GenerarTarjetas = () => {

    const [price, setPrice] = useState('Precio');

    return (
        <>
            <div className="card-boundle animate__animated animate__backInDown animate__delay-1s">

                {                    
                     
                    data.products.map((product) => (

                       

                        <div key={product.id} className="card">

                             
                            <img src={product.image} alt={product.name} />

                            <h2>{product.name}</h2>
                            <span>$ {price}</span>

                            

                            <form className="shop-form">

                                <select onChange={(e) => {
                                    const seleccion = e.target.value;
                                    setPrice(seleccion);
                                }} name="select">

                                    
                                    <option value={product.price[0]}>{product.quant[0]}</option>
                                    <option value={product.price[1]}>{product.quant[1]}</option>
                                    <option value={product.price[2]}>{product.quant[2]}</option>

                                </select>

                                <button>Agregar</button>

                            </form>

                        </div>

                    ))

                }
                

            </div>

        </>

    );
};
```

```
const data = {
    products: [
        {
            id: '1',
            name: 'Tarta de choclo',
            category: 'Tartas',
            image: '../img/1.jpg',
            price: ['120','150','190'],
            quant: ['3','6','9']

        },
        {
            id: '2',
            name: 'Prepizza integral',
            category: 'Pizzas',
            image: '../img/2.jpg',
            price: ['100','200','300'],
            quant: ['3','6','9']

        },
        {
            id: '3',
            name: 'Milanesas de berenjena',
            category: 'Milanesas',
            image: '../img/3.jpg',
            price: ['150','250','300'],
            quant: ['x200g','x500g','x1kg']

        },
        {
            id: '4',
            name: 'Ñoquis de verdura',
            category: 'Pastas',
            image: '../img/4.jpg',
            price: ['190','250','350'],
            quant: ['x200g','x500g','x1kg']

        },
    ],
};


export default data;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creá un componente para la tarjeta en si. Que tenga un estado con la cantidad y la demas info le llega por props como ahora.

ejemplo:

```
const ProductCard = (product) => (
  const [ qty, setQty ] = useState(0)
  <div key={product.id} className="card">
      <img src={product.image} alt={product.name} />

      <h2>{product.name}</h2>
      <span>$ {product.price * qty}</span>
          <select onChange={(e) => {
              const seleccion = e.target.value;
              setQty(seleccion);
          }} name="select">
        {[0, 1, 2].map(q => <option value={q}>{q}</option>)}
      </select>
    <button>Agregar</button>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Deberias agregar mas contexto de tu situación, como por ejemplo: que problema tienes, que has hecho para solucionarlo, cual es el comportamiento actual de tu codigo y cual es el comportamiento esperado, etc.